# Running Wordpress on rails subdirectory using nginx

Tags: wordpress, nginx

I have new wordpress website and existing rails app on two different servers.
I wanted my wordpress website to be https://example.com/blog

My current nginx config for mydomain.com is

```
location /blog {
proxy_pass http://<ip-address of wp server>;
proxy_http_version                  1.1;
proxy_set_header  Connection        "";
proxy_set_header  Host              $host;
proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
}
```

My wordpress config is

```
$_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on';
define('WP_HOME', "https://example.com/blog");
define('WP_SITEURL', "https://example.com/blog");
```

Everything is working fine(admin and home page)
But when i click on post-page on hover its showing right url
which is https://example.com/blog/post but its redirecting to
https://example.com/post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve this by changing my nginx config

```
    location /blog {
  proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_redirect false;

  if (!-f $request_filename) {
    rewrite ^/blog$     /;
    rewrite ^/blog/(.*)$ /$1;
    proxy_pass http://blog.domain.com;
    break;
  }
}
```